# How to avoid circular import when defining own ToJSon

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'd like to add a `self` link to my json export, so I have in `Model.hs`:

```
instance ToJSON (Entity Event) where
    toJSON (Entity eid e) = object
        [ -- , "href" .= render EventR eid ]
```

However I can't seem to do `"href" .= render EventR eid`, because if I try to `Import Handler.Event` I get a circular dependency error

*Edit 1:*

Seems I have another problem, as trying to get the `render` causes an error (as it changes the return value). Is there a way to escape from that?

```
instance ToJSON (Entity Event) where
    toJSON (Entity eid e) = do
      render <- getUrlRender
      return $ object
          [ "href" .= render EventR eid ]
```

Comment: well you could move the `instance` to a place where you have access to both parts

Comment: When I tried to move it to `Event.hs` I got an `orphan instance` warning - so I guess that would be wrong?

Comment: IMO you can ignore this in this special case (the alternative would be to wrap your entity into another type and append the `self`part there - then you could move this together with it's instance up) (sometimes this is called *ViewModel* or *DataTransferObject* - obviously this is OO talk) - thinking about it this could be the better approach as you could unwrap `Event` from it's `Entity` at the same time

Comment: Do you mean create something like `data EventEntity = Event Entity`?

Comment: Hmm, seems I have a bigger problem, as I can't seem to `render <- getUrlRender` from inside toJSON - as the `do` statement changes the return value. oh, the life of a newbie! ;)

-- I'll edit my original issue to reflect this problem

Comment: I was actually wondering about this - if I remember correctly you get `getUrlRender` from the `Yesod` typeclass so you are out of luck here anyway - so go `data MyDto = MyDto Event Url` load your data in this from a yesod-handler (there `getUrlRender` should be available) and make `MyDto` an instance of `ToJSON`)

Comment: alternatively you can just produce `JSON` on the go (by using `toJSON` on the parts but now using any wrapper at all) if you like

Comment: Yes, I think my only option is to add those Yesod-aware parts from within the handler itself. Thanks!